Cannot Find Reference `configure_azure_monitor` from Opentelemetry Library
I'm currently exploring the options of using OpenTelemetry with Azure Application Insights for logging, traces and metrics.
Was following this particular documentation that popped up on Google.
Posting the snippet here, in case if the link expires:
# Import the `configure_azure_monitor()` function from the
# `azure.monitor.opentelemetry` package.
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor

# Import the tracing api from the `opentelemetry` package.
from opentelemetry import trace

# Configure OpenTelemetry to use Azure Monitor with the 
# APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING environment variable.
configure_azure_monitor()

so when I try this in my Python application, I get this Cannot find Reference error for the configure_azure_monitor. Also I have azure-monitor-opentelemetry package installed with version 1.6.0
Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

What do you want to do? any example you want to send to logs?

@RithwikBojja I want to see how I can integrate opentelemetry with azure app insights, so that i can like push metrics from my application

So you want to send to traces?

@RithwikBojja yes that's correct

I posted an answer @kulasanagar, check it.

@RithwikBojja thanks, let me try this and get back to you :)

Sure, It will work. Will wait for your reply.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RithwikBojja thank you im able to push the logs now. But i want to understand is there a difference between pushing it through open telemetry and directly pushing to application insights?

Open Telemetry has multiple advantages if you compare

Glad it worked out for you @kulasangar.

@RithwikBojja hey i did have another question on pushing OTEL metrics to Azure App Insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78793095/how-to-push-open-telemetry-metrics-to-azure-app-insights-using-azure-monitor-met would you be knowing about this as well?

Sure ill check it @Kulasangar


integrate opentelemetry with azure app insights, so that i can like push metrics from my application

The configure_azure_monitor() is  not supported in latest versions of Open Telemetry.
You can use  azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter to send logs to Application Insights using Open Telemetry Package in python.
I have followed Microsoft-Document and able to send the logs.
import logging 
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs.export import BatchLogRecordProcessor as blrp
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorLogExporter as amlp
from opentelemetry._logs import (get_logger_provider as glp,set_logger_provider as slp,)
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import (LoggerProvider,LoggingHandler,)

slp(LoggerProvider())
ri_ex = amlp(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=b6*****00;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=2e74****ddf63"
)
glp().add_log_record_processor(blrp(ri_ex))

ri_han = LoggingHandler()
ri_lger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
ri_lger.addHandler(ri_han )
ri_lger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

ri_lger.warning("Warning Rithwik WARNING ")
ri_lger.error("Error Rithwik")

Output:

