How to push Open Telemetry Metrics to Azure App Insights using Azure Monitor Metric Exporter (Python)?
I'm quite new to Azure and OTEL, and currently exploring the options of integrating Open Telemetry with Application Insights in Azure.
I was able to push traces using the AzureMonitorTraceExporter and I did see them appearing under the Performances in App Insights.
But I'm struggling to send OTEL metrics to Insights. For example, I need to calculate how long did a function took to complete execution, how much memory did it take etc and send those metrics to Application Insights. After sending them to App Insights, from which table can I query those?
I tried searching for this online, but couldn't find any. Any help could be appreciated.

Have you checked below answer @Kulasangar


I need to calculate how long did a function took to complete execution, how much memory did it take

I have used pip install azure-monitor-opentelemetry and  configure_azure_monitor started working for me, before it didn't worked.

By using AzureMonitorTraceExporter, you can send logs but duration is not calculated, only the logs are exported to traces .
For those details you can create Dependency Logs using configure_azure_monitor as below and followed Microsoft_Document:
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace

configure_azure_monitor(connection_string="InstrumentationKey=b641cafc-00;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=2e73")
ri_tr = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
with ri_tr.start_as_current_span("Rithwik Bojja") as rith:
    rith.set_attribute("Id", "007")
    rith.set_attribute("Test ", "testing")
    print("Hello Rithwik, Dependency Logged")

Output:

Here you can duration and all:



